# How can I get the previous resolved query to webhook in API.AI?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a webhook setup with api.ai. The webhook is integrated with youtube api which search for given keywords and return corresponding video. I'm facing a trouble like below

Example conversations with bot:

```
Me: Base 10 equations
bot: Which grade are you studying ?
me: grade 3
```

Then i want to search the keyword “Base 10 equations grade 3” using webhook youtube api and send the most relevant video to api.ai.

I’m getting only the parameter grade 3 to the Webook. But i want both “base 10 equations” and “grade 3” to the webhook to proceed. Can somebody please help me how to proceed ?? Thanks.

Comment: you can mark all parameter required and ask user to provide parameter value in prompt.

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I done using contexts and custom entities in user says. Indeed I marked as a required parameter's. Thanks for your Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was crypto conversions
My case
User: BTC to usd
Bot: 1 BTC = 4000 USD
User: on bittrex
Bot: 1 BTC = 4100 USD on Bittrex

The way I handled this query was by making 2 separate intents: convert and exchanges
The convert intent sets an output context
[image]

The convert Intent sends all the detected entities to my webhook
The exchanges intent has an input context

[image]

Notice the parameters under action, #convert.source and #convert.destination refer to the variables stored while triggering the webhook prior to calling exchanges. That's how you can do it.

In your case I believe one intent handles base 10 and another handles grade 3 and the grade 3 intent refers to #contextname.variable name Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the Input, It's very clear. I don't have Enough reputation to upvote the answer. Although would you mind if I asked how you are using **multipledcurrency:source to multipliedcurrency:destination in exchange:e**  ?? Is this entities ? Also, do I need to add any parameter's in first intent ? I have similar use cases.

Comment: yea its a custom entity i made for detecting those currencies

Comment: Cool. Works great +1 for custom entity in user says and +1 for #contextname.variable name. Thanks man...